# all standart icon for Cordova cli-9.0.0 android and IOS app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

when I develop cordova android and IOS app in some devices I don't see my icon(i see default cordova icon)
How can I see all requirement icons and splash screens?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref/images.html
In this document it say

ICONS

```
 <platform name="android">
              <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
     </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
              <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
              <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
              <!-- iPad -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
              <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
              <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
              <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
              <!-- iPad -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
              <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
              <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
              <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
     </platform>
```

Splash screens

```
  android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png
    android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png
    android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png
    android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png
    android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png
    android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png
    android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png
    android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png


 ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png
    ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png
    ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png
    ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png
    ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png
    ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png
    ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
    ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png
    ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png
```

is this enough?I use this but still see some default cordova icons on some devices

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue by using the **cordova-res** package. I just followed their readme from the GitHub page: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res.

One gotcha: You should reference the platforms you want to have icons for in the config.xml file, like so:

```
<platform name="android">
  <icon src="resources/icon.png" />
</platform>
```

I found it's also necessary to have the folder be called `resources`. Good luck!